# Calling lambda with template parameter list, without providing arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Can anyone tell me whether this ...

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto f = []<typename T>() -> T
    {
        return 123;
    };
    f.operator ()<int>();
}
```

... is the only way to call the C++20 generic lambda without arguments?

Comment: Looks ugly as hell TBH :)

Comment: Good question. Simple, easy, and likely good candidate for a canonical when such question will rise in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the only way to call them.

If the lambda can be changed, consider using a tag:

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

auto f = []<typename T>(tag<T>) {...};
f(tag<int>{});
```